# Pass pointer to go defer function doesn't work

Tags: go, defer-keyword

In my code I try to use `numAddr` to record the change of num after the defer statement

```golang
func deferRun() {
    num := 1
    numAddr := &num
    defer fmt.Printf("num is %d", *numAddr)
    num = 2
    return
}

func main() {
    deferRun()
}
```

but I get `num is 1` instead of 2, why does the defer function use the value instead of address of `*numAddr`?

then I try another way

```golang
func deferRun() {
    num := 1
    numAddr := &num
    defer func(intAddr *int){
        fmt.Printf("num is %d", *numAddr)
    }(numAddr)
    
    num = 2
    fmt.Println("num is", *numAddr)
    return
}

func main() {
    deferRun()
}
```

This time it works and I get `num is 2`, so I think maybe `defer fmt.Printf(something)` stored the string immediately when it was declared and the numAddr is not used when the defer function actually run?

Comment: Duplicate. `*numAddr` is evaluated when when the defer line is executes. At that time `*numAddr == 1` .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting question. To answer the question, you must know a rule, as in this Go tutorial https://go.dev/tour/flowcontrol/12

`The deferred call's arguments are evaluated immediately, but the function call is not executed until the surrounding function returns.`.

**Example 1:** Telling the defer function to print value located in a specified memory address.

```
func deferRun() {
    num := 1
    numAddr := &num //address of variable num in stack memory, 0xc000076f38 for example
    defer func(intAddr *int){
        fmt.Printf("num is %d", *numAddr)
    }(numAddr) //Hey Go, when the surrounding function returns, print the value located in this address (numAddr=0xc000076f38)
    num = 2 //Now the value located in address 0xc000076f38 is 2
    return  
}
```

Output will be 2.

**Example 2:** Telling the defer function to print a specified value.

```
func deferRun() {
    num := 1
    numAddr := &num //address of variable num in stack memory, 0xc000076f38 for example
    defer fmt.Printf("num is %d", *numAddr) //Hey Go, when the surrounding function returns, print the this value *numAddr (*numAddr is 1 for now)
    num = 2 //Now the value located in address 0xc000076f38 is 2 but you told the defer function to print 1 before
    return  
}
```

Output will be 1.